# Php array display first value of multi array

Tags: php

I know this is a simple question but I can't figure it out.

How can I display only the first value (File was not uploaded) from this array? The array can be different! So $test[fileUploadFileErrorNoFile] is not the sollution.

```
$test = Array ( [fileUploadFileErrorNoFile] => File was not uploaded 
                [fileMimeTypeNotReadable] => File is not readable or does not exist 
                [fileIsImageNotReadable] => File is not readable or does not exist 
                [fileImageSizeNotReadable] => File is not readable or does not exist 
            )
```

Comment: array_values($test)[0] ?

Comment: array_pop(array_reverse($array));

Comment: @Daniel1147 thats it! thanks!

Comment: This solution will give you an error if the array is empty

Comment: @Marko Paju is right.

Comment: If you are using array_values($test)[0], use it after checking if $test is not an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$test = Array (   "[fileIsImageNotReadable] => File is not readable or does not exist", "[fileImageSizeNotReadable] => File is not readable or does not exist" );


echo $test[0]; // 0 == the first value
```

Comment: Except the OP's array does not look anything like your example

Answer (score 0):

Does your array look like this?

```
$test = Array (
           Array(
         fileUploadFileErrorNoFile => 'File was not uploaded' ,
         fileMimeTypeNotReadable => 'File is not readable or does not exist',
         fileIsImageNotReadable => 'File is not readable or does not exist', 
         fileImageSizeNotReadable => 'File is not readable or does not exist'
         )
    );
```

Then the answer would be:

```
echo $test[0][fileUploadFileErrorNoFile];
```

Comment: Except the OP's array does not look anything like your example